# Can't boot any OS after installing Windows. "GNU GRUB Minimal Bash-like line editing is supported"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

So I recently created a small partition on my HDD and installed Windows 10 on it.

Once I restarted it would only boot into Windows, I expected that though. I then booted Boot-Repair-Disk and went through the steps so as to repair and get a boot menu when I start my laptop.

HOWEVER, once rebooted it goes to a black screen which says:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu11.2
Minimal Bash-like line editing is supported.
```

I have tried a few things from that screen though nothing seems to have repaired it yet. I was thinking it might be a good idea to boot the live/trail CD (USB) and then try to repair/reinstall GRUB, however I wouldn't know what commands to run in terminal.

Here's a [pastebin link](https://preview.ibb.co/dikMHa/IMG_20170525_004906.jpg) which was given by Boot-Repair-Disk.

I think, although I'm not sure, that GRUB was on sda1.
When I went through the process it seemed to be making changes to sda6 (my main ubuntu partition, about 400gb). Windows is installed on sda2.

Any ideas as to how I can get it to boot to GRUB and then select Ubuntu or Windows, or if that isn't possible just to boot Ubuntu, would be greatly appreciated.

---

Since posting I tried to run the live cd and repair GRUB and I also installed 17.04 on unallocated space as I thought that doing so might repair the bootloader. I also did this to make sure that I could still access the files in the sda6 partition. I can although some say that I don't have permission to access.

This is my HDD in GParted in live CD/USB:

[image: photo of screen with partitions in gparted]

Those are all of the partitions. The 23.08GB (sda7) is new since I posted the pastebin link. All the other partitions are as they were though.

Comment: I tried this:

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

but it didnt solve the problem.

I can access the Ubuntu partition with the live usb, so i will be able to recover files. However would really like to be able to repair Grub without having to do a fresh install. Any ideas???

Comment: Please accept your answer by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: @dessert Agreed. This Q&A with 10K views was bumped to homepage by Community today for review. Another 2 minutes lost in our lives! I upvoted the answer hoping this won't happen again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it!!!!

This link was very useful:

[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Boot repair didn't work when I tried with a USB and the terminal commands didn't work either, but when I booted the live USB and installed boot-repair then ran it and told it to install to the new partition sda7 (the one with 17.04). I rebooted and the GRUB menu appeared!! I can now choose the 16.10 from the menu and it boots fine.

It does take longer now and when booting there are a lot of messages like `starting... such and such`.

Windows boots fine and 17.04 boots fine also. I might try to start using 17.10 as I can access all my files on the 400gb 16.10 partition from there.

***I should mention that before doing all that I restored the MBR with the Boot-Repair Lubuntu tool.***

Comment: I don't think that link ever worked. It's `...` to shorten the whole thing so it's how links are displayed in some systems and not the actual link that works.